# Microsoft Bot Framework Composer Teams package Send task module

Tags: bot-framework-composer

How do you use the Send task module Teams options? Should invoking open a new Teams Task module? Can I have an intent directly open a task module?

[image]

I have setup the following task, but nothing happens in Teams when this response is triggered. Should a Teams task message appear?

[image]

https://github.com/microsoft/botframework-components/tree/main/packages/Teams/dotnet

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following page details how the Teams task module message responses work.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/task-modules-and-cards/task-modules/task-modules-bots